# Pandas interpolate is filling nan rather than interpolating

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I have a dataframe, which is resampled to higher sampling rate like from 8hz to 16 hz.using

```
new_df = new_df.resample('62.5L').ffill()
```

[image: the image before upsampling is here]

instead of using `ffill()`, I tried to interpolate values using

```
interpolated = new_df.interpolate(method='linear', axis=0)
```

but the new data frame is having "nan"  filled rather than interpolated values
[image: THE IMAGE AFTER UP SAPLING AND INTERPOLATING]

Can anyone please help me in interpolating without filling nan in the columns !

Comment: Thank you for reply. But following code worked. I had to convert each particular column to float if it is numeric data and then use interpolate command. for text columns I used fill.  1. for numeric data: df.iloc[:,1,2,3].astype(float).interpolate() 2. for text data: ips.iloc[:,bbbb].ffill()

Answer (score 0):

```
interpolated = new_df.interpolate(method='time', axis=0)
```

This should work. I understand it's not linear (I'm not exactly sure why its giving `NaN`) but seeing as the difference between each timestamp is equal. This should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But following code worked. I had to convert each particular column to float if it is numeric data and then use interpolate command. for text columns I used fill.  1. for numeric data: df.iloc[:,1,2,3].astype(float).interpolate() 2. for text data: ips.iloc[:,bbbb].ffill()